# std::copy runtime_error when working with uint16_t's

Tags: c++11, vector, copy, uint16

I'm looking for input as to why this breaks.  See the addendum for contextual information, but I don't really think it is relevant.

I have an `std::vector<uint16_t> depth_buffer` that is initialized to have 640*480 elements.  This means that the total space it takes up is `640*480*sizeof(uint16_t) = 614400`.

The code that breaks:

```
void Kinect360::DepthCallback(void* _depth, uint32_t timestamp) {
    lock_guard<mutex> depth_data_lock(depth_mutex);

    uint16_t* depth = static_cast<uint16_t*>(_depth);
    std::copy(depth, depth + depthBufferSize(), depth_buffer.begin());/// the error
    new_depth_frame = true;
}
```

where `depthBufferSize()` will return 614400 (I've verified this multiple times).

My understanding of `std::copy(first, amount, out)` is that `first` specifies the memory address to start copying from, `amount` is how far in bytes to copy *until*, and `out` is the memory address to start copying to.

Of course, it can be done manually with something like

```
#pragma unroll
for(auto i = 0; i < 640*480; ++i) depth_buffer[i] = depth[i];
```

instead of the call to `std::copy`, but I'm really confused as to why `std::copy` fails here.  Any thoughts???

---

Addendum: the context is that I am writing a derived class that inherits from `FreenectDevice` to work with a Kinect 360.  Officially the error is a `Bus Error`, but I'm almost certain this is because libfreenect interprets an error in the `DepthCallback` as a `Bus Error`.  Stepping through with `lldb`, it's a standard `runtime_error` being thrown from `std::copy`.  If I manually enter `depth + 614400` it will crash, though if I have `depth + (640*480)` it will chug along.  At this stage I am not doing something meaningful with the depth data (rendering the raw depth *appropriately* with OpenGL is a separate issue xD), so it is hard to tell if *everything* got copied, or just a portion.  That said, I'm almost positive it doesn't grab it all.

Contrasted with the corresponding `VideoCallback` and the call inside of `copy(video, video + videoBufferSize(), video_buffer.begin())`, I don't see why the above would crash.  If my understanding of `std::copy` were wrong, this should crash too since `videoBufferSize()` is going to return `640*480*3*sizeof(uint8_t) = 640*480*3 = 921600`.  The `*3` is from the fact that we have 3 `uint8_t`'s per pixel, RGB (no A).  The `VideoCallback` works swimmingly, as verified with OpenGL (and the fact that it's essentially identical to the samples provided with libfreenect...).  FYI none of the samples I have found actually work with the raw depth data directly, all of them colorize the depth and use an `std::vector<uint8_t>` with RGB channels, which does not suit my needs for this project.

---

I'm happy to just ignore it and move on in some senses because I can get it to work, but I'm really quite perplexed as to why this breaks.  Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `std::copy` works is that you provide start and end points of your input sequence and the location to begin copying to. The end point that you're providing is off the end of your sequence, because your `depthBufferSize` function is giving an offset in bytes, rather than the number of elements in your sequence.

If you remove the multiply by `sizeof(uint16_t)`, it will work. At that point, you might also consider calling `std::copy_n` instead, which takes the number of elements to copy.

Edit: I just realised that I didn't answer the question directly.
Based on my understanding of `std::copy`, it shouldn't be throwing exceptions with the input you're giving it. The only thing in that code that could throw a runtime_error is the locking of the mutex.
Considering you have undefined behaviour as a result of running off of the end of your buffer, I'm tempted to say that has something to do with it.

Comment: I don't understand.  If that were so, then the endpoint would have to still be `depth + (total size of depth data)`, which includes the multiple of `sizeof(uint16_t)`, no?  Otherwise I would get exactly the first half of the depth data (2bytes = 1 short). As in the endpoint of the depth data must account for the fact that I am using `uint16_t` here (shorts) instead of `uint8_t`'s (bytes). Or are you saying that because `depth_buffer` is an `std::vector<uint16_t>`, copy knows to go that far?  I feel like this is overwhelmingly obvious, thank you for your patience!

Comment: The type of your pointers affects how they are incremented inside of the copy algorithm; it's all pointer arithmetic. When you add the result of `depthBufferSize` to your `depth` pointer, the pointer is advanced by that many uint16_t's, it's not advanced that many 'bytes'.

Comment: Ahhhhhh I see!!!  Putting it in terms of pointers cleared it up for me, thanks :)  That also explains why the `VideoCallback` was functional -- precisely because `sizeof(uint8_t) = 1`.  Thanks again!